# How to calculate Customer since i.e Duration of customer in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to find out how long a person has been a customer.
I mean I simply want to subtract current date from start date.
However I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
customerStartDate: String;
currentDate: any = '';
this.customerStartDate = this.sampleData1.customerStartDate;    
this.currentDate = new Date();
// Get Customer Age
this.customerAge = this.currentDate.getTime() - this.customerStartDate.getTime();
```

However current age is giving error.
How can I calculate the Customer Duration in typescript.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'String' on customerAge and getTime doesn't exist on this.customerStartDate.getTime()

Comment: this.customerStartDate is it a timestamp? and change the currentDate to Date type

Comment: Yes customerStartDate is timestamp

Comment: Mind if you paste a sample of how `sampleData1.customerStartDate` can look like?

Comment: And what format do you need the time difference to in? Hours? Days? Minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should convert `customerStartDate` to a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

```
this.customerStartDate = new Date(this.sampleData1.customerStartDate);
```

Then, you get the difference between today's date and `customerStartDate`, which will be in milliseconds.

```
this.currentDate = new Date();
this.customerAge = this.currentDate - this.customerStartDate;
```

If you wish to convert it to a readable format (display days, minutes, etc), you can do something like this:

```js
const convertToReadableTime = time => {
  const days = Math.floor(time / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  const daysMs = time % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const hours = Math.floor((daysMs) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
  const hoursMs = time % (60 * 60 * 1000);
  const minutes = Math.floor((hoursMs) / (60 * 1000));
  const minutesMs = time % (60 * 1000);
  const seconds = Math.floor((minutesMs) / (1000));
  return `${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes, and ${seconds} seconds`;
}

console.log(convertToReadableTime(736771945325));
```

Comment: How do I calculate months. I mean I got years by dividing number of days by 365 but for months what do I do

Comment: @Ahmed It might be tricky to calculate months because some months have 31 days and some have 30 days. In addition, in the month of February, there might be 28/29 days, depending if it is a leap year? Unless, you are alright if we set a 'fixed' number of days for each month. I.e 1 month = 30 days?

Comment: I was stuck on that too about 31 and 30 days... never mind I understood it. Thank you so much for helping out

Answer (score 1):

```
           customerStartDate: any;
            currentDate: any;
            this.customerStartDate = this.sampleData1.customerStartDate;    
            this.currentDate = new Date();
            // Get Customer Age in Days
var diff=this.currentDate.getTime() - new Date(this.customerStartDate).getTime()
            this.customerAge = this.calculateYears(diff/(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //in Days


    calculateYears(){
    if (days < 0)
    {
        date2_UTC.setMonth(date2_UTC.getMonth() - 1);
        days += DaysInMonth(date2_UTC);
    }

    var months = date2_UTC.getMonth() - date1_UTC.getMonth();
    if (months < 0)
    {
        date2_UTC.setFullYear(date2_UTC.getFullYear() - 1);
        months += 12;
    }

    var years = date2_UTC.getFullYear() - date1_UTC.getFullYear();


    if (years > 1) yAppendix = " years";
    else yAppendix = " year";
    if (months > 1) mAppendix = " months";
    else mAppendix = " month";
    if (days > 1) dAppendix = " days";
    else dAppendix = " day";

    return years + yAppendix + ", " + months + mAppendix + ", and " + days + dAppendix + " old.";
    }
```

Comment: error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'String'.
error TS2345: Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
  Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: make customerAge type to any like customerAge:any

Comment: I want the result in year, months and days elapsed. something like this 2 years 1 Month and 11 days

Comment: Done the changes